# Make JMS queue aware of the state of the events that are being processed. Is it possible to configure in ActiveMQ?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, producer-consumer, task-queue

I'm trying to configure a queue that is aware of the events that are being processed.

**Questions**

1. Does this make sense? :)
2. Is it possible to configure/customize ActiveMQ?
3. Are there any other library that can be "easily" configured to handle such cases? Kafka?

**Problem**
The queue contains events. Each event is associated with an object. A consumer takes the event from the queue and performs a task. Each event should be taken only by exactly one consumer.

**Constraints**

1. Events for the same object cannot be processed concurrently.
2. But events for different objects should be processed in parallel.

**Example**

The queue is

- ObjectA-Event1
- ObjectA-Event2
- ObjectB-Event1
- ObjectC-Event1

The Consumer1 should receive ObjectA-Event1 from the queue. The Consumer2 should receive ObjectB-Event1 from the queue and not the ObjectA-Event2. The ObjectA-Event2 should be available for consumers only when the first consumer completes the task for the ObjectA-Event1.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you should use [message groups](https://activemq.apache.org/message-groups). Messages for each object should be in the same group so that they are received by the same consumer and processed serially. Messages in different groups are free to be processed by different consumers.